# Creating a cold multi-coin wallet that can make transactions

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency

Based on my limited knowledge for making a transaction you need to have a public address, a private key and a destination public address, together, these three can form a transaction which we will broadcast to the blockchain for it to execute. Now what I want to do is to store both the public key and the private key on a computer that is not connected to the internet and then when I want to make a transaction I will give it the destination address and it will form a transaction then through QR code I will broadcast this transaction to the blockchain using my phone or another computer, this way my private key never touches any piece of equipment that is not safe.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to create a truly cold wallet as Bitcoin requires transaction IDs from previous transactions to make new transactions, therefore, one should come up with a way to update the wallet with recent transactions.
In order to create a QR Code based wallet there should be two PCs with two cameras and screens so the PC that is connected to the internet can update the one that isn't.